# Difficulty in understanding float function in pseudocode

Tags: raptor

I am just a beginner. I am learning programming right now and I am having problem in understanding few functions like float and cieling, I would like to know when and why do we use them?

Comment: Have you tried reading a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about float if you talk about the variable float, you will use it when you have a number that has decimals,you can learn more about it just searching in Google